# How to check for duplicates, highlight duplicates, and count the highlighted duplicates in a single column?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to highlight and count the number of duplicates in a single concatenated column.

I have it as two separate subs right now and there really isn't much more to say, this isn't that hard of a problem I'm confident of that but I have been working on it for days with absolutely no progress. It has to be done in a VBA and it cannot highlight blank cells in the column. The concatenations are done through a formula in the workbook. Please help me, I m dying,

```
Sub Duplicate_Check()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheet1

     Worksheets("Master Checklist").Activate

        Columns("H:H").Select
        Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
        Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .ColorIndex = 40
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    'Sheet2.Range(“L2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(Columns("H:H")), cell.Font.Color = "-16383844")
    'Range(“B10?).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(Range(“A2:A8?), “>” & 50
   End Sub

   Sub CountDupes()
     Dim countofDupes As Long
     Dim rng As Range
     Dim myCell As Range
    countofDupes = 0
    Set rng = Range("H2").End(xlDown)
    For Each myCell In rng
    If myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 40 Then
    countofDupes = countofDupes + 1
    Debug.Print countofDupes
    End If
    Next myCell

     End Sub
```

I don't encounter any error messages but if I `Debug.Print countofDupes` I get nothing returned, which it obviously not what I want. Any advice?

Comment: `Range("H2").End(xlDown)` is a single cell, equivalent to going to H2 and pressing Ctrl and the down arrow.

Comment: `Duplicate_Check` adds conditional formatting. In `CountDupes`, you need to check `myCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex`.

Comment: Couldn't you just use one of the built-in Conditional Formats, then use `COUNTIF()`?

Comment: @BigBen I believe you may have saved a life